# FindQt4 fails to link QtOpenGL project properly

Tags: qt, opengl, linker, cmake

Projects that use the QtOpenGL fail to link to gl calls, but *only* on Windows (Linux is happy). The MSVC 2008 error messages for the following minimal case project are:

```
1>gllink.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ImageWidget::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@ImageWidget@@MAEXXZ)
1>gllink.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4 referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ImageWidget::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@ImageWidget@@MAEXXZ)
1>gllink.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

These errors disappear when I manually add "opengl32.lib" to the "Additional Dependencies" list, but I believe this should not be necessary, since this should either be done by FindQt4.cmake, or should be taken care of by the dependency of QtOpenGL on opengl32. Of course, I must be mistaken, so I would really appreciate some input on how to properly fix this project.

**gllink.cpp**

```
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <QWidget>

class ImageWidget : public QGLWidget
{
public:
   ImageWidget(QWidget* parent = 0) :
      QGLWidget(parent)
   {
   }

protected:
   void initializeGL()
   {
      glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
      glLoadIdentity();
   }
};

int main()
{
   ImageWidget w;
   return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
PROJECT( gllink )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 4.6.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL )
INCLUDE( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( gllink gllink.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( gllink ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FindQt4 doesn't take care of that, you have to search for OpenGL by yourself. Now CMake provides a FindOpenGL package, so fixing your project is just a matter of adding `find_package( OpenGL )` and linking the libraries to your target:

```
PROJECT( gllink )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenGL )

FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 4.6.0 REQUIRED QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL )
INCLUDE( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( gllink gllink.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( gllink ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

Btw, you should check if those libraries are really found and warn the user about the problem if they're not :)